# Window functions with variable size

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, analytics

I'm trying to compute a sum over a variable window in SQL. Ultimately, I'm trying to

```sql
sum(num_requests) over (
    partition by user_id
    order by request_date
    rows between lookback preceding and current row
) as num_requests_in_period
```

This seems to fail as instead of a column "lookback" number, Snowflake expects a integer.

Here's the context. I have a log with that register every time a user makes a request. From that table, I generate a derived table that for every user/date combination, it gives me the number of requests a user generated. The table has this schema:

```sql
create table user_daily_requests (
  user_id int,
  request_date date,
  total_requests integer
)
```

I have a separate subscription table, that for every date/user combination, gives me the start and end billing period.

```sql
create table as subscription_snapshot (
  snapshot_date date,
  user_id int,
  billing_period_start date,
  billing_period_end date
)
```

I got this working by joining the daily requests with subcriptions on the billing period dates. And then aggregating.

```sql
[...]
from subscription_snapshot s
left join user_daily_requests r on
  s.billing_period_start <= r.request_data
  and r.request_data < s.billing_period_start
[...]
```

I'm now looking to implementing this with a window function. Similar if I'd be computing the last 7 or 30 days. The `lookback` would be the number of days since the billing periods start. Is this possible?

Comment: Please provide sample data for both tables, along with the result you are looking for. Showing your entire actual query would also help.

Comment: Is the error that snowflake expects a constant as that argument and cant be a value from a column? If so, thats annoying. I would try to reformat your approach to extracting the dates you care about themselves (Maybe a MAX() off of your range join subquery) , and then do DATEDIFF to calc the days between them